# Insert an image bound by coordinates with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that it's possible to place an image within a node at precise coordinates, and to scale the image:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node at (1,1) {
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{"image"}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, what I want to do is to choose a rectangle with coordinates and place an image to fit inside:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node at (1,1) rectangle (4,4) {
    \includegraphics{"image"}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thus, it can precisely be positioned relatively to other elements like lines.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please always post compilable code rather than fragments.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate. I already explored that link but all it provides is an answer that uses `\textwidth` (which isn't what I want because I am looking for coordinates) and a draw command with a `path` style, but the image doesn't fit inside (unless it is example-image).

Comment: You don't have to use `\textwidth`, obviously. You can specify the coordinate however you like. E.g. `\path[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);` substituting `6,4` for `\textwidth,4cm`. It fits inside for me. Also works with the standard `tiger` image.  If you don't want it cropped in the other direction use e.g. `\path[fill stretch image=tiger] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);` but, obviously, the image will be distorted in that case.

Comment: @cfr: it does precisely what I was looking for. Thanks! To sum it up: all I need is to add `\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}` in the header and then write `\path[fill stretch image=my_image] (1,1) rectangle (4,4);` inside a `tikzpicture` block.